# MySQL Order the Group By

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a query:

```
SELECT * FROM quotes q INNER JOIN users u ON q.wp_user_id = u.ID
WHERE q.created >= '$startDate' AND q.created <= '$endDate'
GROUP BY q.wp_user_id
```

This works fine but where I am grouping I am not getting the correct row from the group. I am looking to order the group by $table.roofarea but adding this to the end obviously just orders the entire query not just the group by section.

I hope this makes sense, any questions just ask!

Cheers

Comment: Not sure I follow, which line would you like to get per group? The one with the biggest roof area?

Comment: how did you manage to "select *" without including all columns in the group by clause

Comment: Why are you using group by to begin with if you are not performing any aggregate calculations?

Comment: Please add the tables' actual names. `$table` and `$table2` help no-one understand what info is in which table, what columns are the PKs, etc.

Comment: I have amended the query to include the real names.

The group by wp_user_id groups two rows together from the quotes table but I want to be able to define which of those rows are used i.e. the row with the biggest quotes.roofarea

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right following ORDER BY expresion will help

```
ORDER BY $table.wp_user_id, $table.roofarea
```